# Assigning a shared_ptr to another after calling get

Tags: c++, pointers, move, shared-ptr, move-semantics

```
shared_ptr<std::string> shared_ptr1 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Foo");
shared_ptr<std::string> shared_ptr2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Bar"); 

std::string* normal_ptr = shared_ptr1.get(); 
shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2;
```

Now, **will the first string "Foo" be garbage collected** after the "*shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2*" assignment? According to [this](https://ideone.com/oiMd4F) , "Foo" isn't garbage collected. But I just want to make sure that what I am encountering isn't an undefined behavior.

Thank you!

Comment: Shared ownership is not ”garbage collection”.  You cannot change the ownership of a shared object.

Comment: We don't really know exactly *what* you're encountering. But I suspect it has to do with the pointer `normal_ptr` becoming invalid after the assignment `shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2`?

Comment: @molbdnilo `std::shared_ptr` can be seen as C++'s way of supporting reference counting. Reference counting is a valid form of garbage collection. I believe the view point that `std::shared_ptr` is a form of garbage collection to be fair.

Comment: You are reading in deleted memory. If you run your code with valgrind, you'll see the errors.

Comment: By the way, the literal constant string `"Foo"` itself will *always* be valid throughout the full lifetime of the process. The `std::string` object you create with `std::make_shared<std::string>` will not be alive after the aforementioned assignment.

Comment: You can’t deduce anything from the code you linked; it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `shared_ptr` is a shared object, with a lifetime as long as its longest-lived owner. Reference-counting is the (rather obvious) implementation mechanism supporting shared ownership, not the other way around.

Comment: @molbdnilo No doubt. But it's also true that smart pointers automate the management of lifetime, and by implications, usually automates the management of memory. I'm not a fan of the point of view, but I don't think those who say `shared_ptr` implements garbage collection are strictly wrong.

Comment: What is "moved" where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, will the first string "Foo" be garbage collected after the "shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2" assignment?*

If you mean will the string that was allocated by `std::make_shared<std::string>("Foo")` be destroyed, then yes.

That means that `normal_ptr`, after you do `shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2;` points to an object that no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the phrase "garbage collected". After the mentioned assignment, the object will be simply deleted because no shared_ptr points to it. You can test it with the following code:

```
struct S{
    std::string s;
    S(std::string s){
        this->s = s;
    }
    ~S(){
        std::cout << "~S() with string " << s << std::endl;   
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<S> shared_ptr1 = std::make_shared<S>("Foo");
    std::shared_ptr<S> shared_ptr2 = std::make_shared<S>("Bar"); 

    S* normal_ptr = shared_ptr1.get(); 
    std::cout << "after get()" << std::endl;
    shared_ptr1 = shared_ptr2;
    std::cout << "end of main" << std::endl;
}
```

which gives

```
after get()
~S() with string Foo
end of main
~S() with string Bar
```

which means that after the assignment, `normal_ptr` points to non-existing object.